# Setting Unity's External Script Editor to Visual Studio Causes Errors

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Visual Studio was not giving autocomplete suggestions because in Unity, the external script editor (under Edit > Preferences > External Tools) was set to "open by file extension" and not "Visual Studio Community." But, switching to Visual Studio Community caused a whole host of seemingly random errors. In the bottom half one file, all references to variables declared in the class give "the name '[insert variable name]' does not exist in the current context," despite the fact that the same variables work perfectly fine in the upper half of the file. It gives a"} expected" error despite the fact that there are several closing brackets below. Plus, there are other errors which I don't understand: [part of the error list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDElN.png) Switching back to "open by file extension" makes the errors go away, but then I can't use the autocomplete.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It would be helpful if you added your `PlayerController.cs` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that retyping all the code got rid of the errors. Still no idea what caused it though.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack overflow. That's interesting question. Have you checked
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/get-started/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?pivots=windows) ??? Try steps that you might missed during installation. Also tick "embedded packages" checkbox